# Problems with using themes in Geany

Tags: 11.10, themes, geany

I'm trying to switch to the Geany editor for my web development but need to switch to a dark theme. In searching for some default themes I came across [this](https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes) excellent collection.

I've now installed the themes and they appear when I go to View -> Editor -> Color and I can select one. However, selecting a theme does nothing.

I am running Geany 0.20 (the latest version on Ubuntu 11.10) and have tried installing the new version and the deprecated version of the themes but get the same from both.

Comment: Works fine for me. Try restarting geany.

Comment: Try installing the themes by just running `./install`

Comment: @Capt.Nemo Did you install the master branch or deprecated branch version?

Comment: master`````````

Comment: Geany does not work with Ubuntu dark theme. You can put all the color scheme you prefer but it will look ugly. Especially the "compiler" window is impossible to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happened with me too , you need to copy all the colorschemes in ~/.config/geany/colorschemes and the next step which was not mentioned anywhere is you also need to copy the files in filedefs folder in the zip to corresponding folder in ~/.config/geany/filedefs and then it will start working !!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same Geany (0.2) and Ubuntu (11.10) as yours, and the following commands worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes.git
cd geany-themes
./install
```

Make sure that you have

1. Geany installed. [Click To Install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/geany)
2. Restart geany after installation

Comment: I uninstalled, removed ~/.config/geany, reinstalled, opened geany, installed the themes, killed geany and reopened then selected a theme. For some reason it won't save my theme selection.

Comment: Try filing a bug, or contacting a developer.